# Implementing StockTwits share in WordPress sharing

Tags: stocktwits

I'd like to use the StockTwits sharing button via the WordPress jetpack sharing functionality, but it does not allow a javascript in the field (under "add a new service")

Is there a URL structure I would use to push a properly formatted request via a URL?

I had tried:

http://stocktwits.com/widgets/share?data-text=%22From%20@optionsideacentral:%20%post_title%%20%post_url%%22

with %post_title% and %post_url% as variables that WP would fill in when clicked, but it didn't work.

Is there something similar that would function right and open a share window and populate the post in that format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can pass body content like the following:
**https://stocktwits.com/widgets/share?body=test%20title**

We will look into seeing how we can support the Jetpack functionality in the future.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, that's great.  Just for knowledge, are there any attributes other than "body" that can be inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Put the JS script in the footer.

Working: (scroll to the bottom)
http://chartyourtrade.com/2014/08/top-10-setups-bases-08232014/